# SSIS Parameters cannot be resolved by dtexec

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dts

I am trying to set a parameter while executing a package from command line

```
dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx /set \package.variables[$Project::MRNS_Database].Value;myvalue
```

I get the below error

> The package path referenced an object that cannot be found:
>   "\Project.Variables[$Project::MRNS_Database]". This occurs when an
>   attempt is made to resolve a package path to an object that cannot be
>   found.

In fact the MRNS_Database is actually a parameter set at project level (I can see this under Parameters in Package Explorer). Also I am not able to use the /Par switch as i am using /File option.

How do i set the parameter in this case from command line dtsexec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify ISPAC Project file as well, like this example

```
DTEXEC /Project "Path to proj\YourProj.ispac" /Package "yourpackage.dtsx"  
/Set \Package.Variables[$Project::MRNS_Database];yourvalue
```

More details in Microsoft [dtexec Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility).

Answer (score 2):

As Ferdipux points out you need to reference your ispac file. Make sure you have builed your project otherwise it can cause errors.

> Make sure everything is on ONE line if you use bat file.
>   I also included package parameters if you have those.

**Bat file**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO This is a batch file
ECHO.

DTEXEC.EXE /Project "C:\Users\thoje\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services Project8\Integration Services Project8\bin\Development\Integration Services Project8.ispac" /Package Package24.dtsx /Set \Package.Variables[User::Test3].Value;1 /set \Package.Variables[$Package::Test2];1 /set  \Package.Variables[$Project::Test4];1
PAUSE
CLS
```